# How to retrieve large amount of image from resources and randomly assign to different Picturebox?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I need to retrieve 25 images from resources and put them into 25 picturebox randomly without any repetition happening. The process should be done automatically when the page loaded from the very beginning. I had named the picture as 1-25 and i suppose this could help the process.

Do we have any way to complete this process. Sorry for my poor language expression. Please help me, thanks.

Comment: That's called a "random shuffle".  There are hundreds of questions about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**One way (could be not the best in performance):**
You need to generate the random numbers and store it in a list.
If the generated number is already present in the list, you get another one... at the end... you will have all the numbers

**This one is better:**

```
    Dim rand As New Random()
    Dim new_list As New List(Of Image)
    Do While Pictures.Count > 0
        ' Move a random Image to the new list.
        Dim i As Integer = rand.Next(0, Pictures.Count)
        new_list.Add(Pictures(i))
        Pictures.RemoveAt(i)
    Loop
```

"Pictures" is a collection of images.
This code was taken from here: http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_net_random_picture_forms.html

Comment: Thank for your answer, i will explore more on this.